# Longest subarray with sum less than equal to k

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of positive integers a, and an integer k, I'm trying to figure out an algorithm which will give me the length of the longest subarray, the sum of which is *less than or equal* to k. I have figured out how to solve it in O(n^2) time, but am trying to solve in in as close to O(n) as I can.

For a O(n) solution, I'm trying to create a start index and an end index, which will give me a window. I want to check if the sum within this window is <= k AND if the length of this window is greater than the last recorded length. However, when typing it out, my logic breaks down.

Comment: Sometimes you have to move the start more than once for a single `i`. So, try wrapping your `else` case body in a `while (sum > k)`.

Comment: I haven't looked very closely, but a quick glance shows that you never assign anything to `maxLen`. I'm guessing `currLen = maxLen` is backwards. Have you tried using a debugger and a simple test case?

Comment: It seems maxLen never gets updated and is output as 0 each time. I'm having a bit of trouble since I have to check for both maximum length AND sum <= k.

Comment: sub-array means elements that are sequential [start,length]?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
 maxLen = currLen;
```

I don't think its part of your problem but you don't use `end` and I don't think it's updated correctly. Just remove it.

Comment: Fixed it, its working now!